# Using correctly HAVING with group by and COUNT

Tags: sql, mysql

I am running this query:

```
SELECT u.id as id, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT YEAR(TIMESTAMP), WEEK(TIMESTAMP)) cc, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT YEAR(TIMESTAMP),'-',WEEK(TIMESTAMP)) a
FROM   users u 
       JOIN checkins c 
         ON c.userid = u.id 
GROUP  BY userid
HAVING COUNT(cc) = 3
```

And this produces the following results:

```
id  cc  a
05  3   2010-43,2010-47,2010-45 
06  2   2010-44,2010-45 
13  3   2010-43,2010-45,2010-48 
20  3   2010-45,2010-43,2010-47 
21  3   2010-43,2010-47,2010-45 
22  2   2010-47,2010-48 
25  3   2010-48,2010-43,2010-46 
27  2   2010-42,2010-47 
30  2   2010-48,2010-45 
41  3   2010-44,2010-45,2010-47 
44  2   2010-42,2010-44 
50  2   2010-44,2010-47 
52  2   2010-48,2010-47 
57  2   2010-43,2010-44 
71  3   2010-43,2010-48,2010-47 
72  2   2010-43,2010-44 
78  3   2010-47,2010-42,2010-43 
79  2   2010-45,2010-46 
80  2   2010-46,2010-44 
87  1   2010-46 
97  1   2010-48 
108 3   2010-43,2010-47,2010-45
```

As you see the `cc` column has values 2, 3, or even 1.

How that comes, when I've told with HAVING that should be 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does allow aliases in the Having clause. You would need to use:

```
HAVING cc = 3
```

not

```
HAVING COUNT(cc) = 3
```

in order to filter the results to only include rows which have a `cc` value of 3 though. I'm actually quite unsure though why `HAVING COUNT(cc) = 3` would return any results at all.

Answer (score 1):

As previously said about aliases and having clause, I'd just like to expand on it.

You already have created `cc` alias which holds counts that you'd like to filter on, so you just need to reference aliased column in HAVING, like:

```
HAVING cc = 3
```

What you have tried (`COUNT(cc) = 3`) would make sense if you were to group by cc column (if that was possible), and then that would filter out all rows with same cc value that didn't appear exactly 3 times.